# How do I find out linux gateway IP address?

Tags: linux-networking, gateway, route, ifconfig, dynamic-ip

I have CentOS 6.7 with two Internet connections

eth0 - dynamic IP address and dynamic gateway via DHCP (controlled by NetworkManager)

ppp0 - dynamic IP address and dynamic gateway (configured with rp_pppoe)

I want write script which will change the default gateway on in some conditions something like this:

```
ip route replace default scope global via $IP1 dev eth0
# or
ip route replace default scope global via $IP2 dev ppp0
# or
ip route replace default scope global nexthop via $IP1 dev eth0 weight 8 nexthop via $IP2 dev ppp0 weight 10
```

**How to find out dynamic gateway $IP1 and $IP2?**

update:

from this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124341/157086

in file  /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient.leases I can find gateway to eth0

```
option routers 12.34.59.28;
```

**How to find out dynamic gateway $IP2 for ppp0?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For eth0:

```
#!/bin/bash    
gwip=$(nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4-SETTINGS.GATEWAY: | awk '{ print $2}')
ip route replace default scope global via $gwip dev eth0
```

for ppp0:

```
#!/bin/bash 
gwip2=$(/sbin/ip addr show ppp0 | grep peer | awk ' { print $4 } ' | sed 's/\/32//')
ip route replace default via $gwip2 dev ppp0
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Alex mention `netstat -r`, if that's not available there is also another way:

```
$ ip route list dev eno1
default via X.X.X.X  proto static  metric 100 
X.X.X.X/24  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X  metric 100 
$
```

replace `eno1` with your device.

`dhclient -R routers` - I can't test it, as I don't have `dhcp` set-up anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For the `ppp0` device you can query the IP address of the **peer** with `ip addr show ppp0`.

However, you don’t even need one, as for a point-to-point device like `ppp0` you can simply set the route only to the interface, omitting the router IP.

Answer (score 0):

This command will give you all the routes set in your Linux machine, including gateway:

```
route -n
```

Comment: NOT! If I in networkmanager config write option DEFROUTE=no I cannot view gateway in route -n

Comment: route is deprecated, you should use ```ip``` instead